# (inline/shrink/auto?)flex grandparent -> flex parent -> flex-basis (DOA)

Tags: css, flexbox, nested

I'm working on a custom `<tab-view>` with the following markup semantics:

```css
#tab-wrapper, #slot {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#slot {
    flex: auto 1 auto;
}

.tab {
    flex: 1 1 10em;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

#new {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="tab-wrapper">
    <div id="slot">
        <div class="tab">test1</div>
        <div class="tab">test2</div>
    </div>
    <span id="new">✚</span>
<div>
```

But what I want is something like this:

[image: required tab layout]

I need the `flex-basis` of the tabs to be `10em` initially, but also allow them to shrink when more tabs are open than there is available space.

I'm not worried about overflow or anything like that, just that the `#new` element comes after the tabs with their preferred `10em` flex basis.

I've tried `flex-shrink: auto` but it has the same effect as `flex-shrink: 1`.

`flex-shrink: 0` is not an option because I want them to be able to shrink - and in this case `flex-shrink: 0` makes the `#new` tab button go out of view completely.

Note: the tab items themselves are also custom elements and don't use any styling other than the default `display: inline` but that shouldn't matter here.

Comment: I looked for similar questions, but if this is a dup, my apology, please mark it as such.  But I found a solution.  Turns out, `min-width`, `max-width` and `width` play very nicely with `flex: 1 1 auto`.  If anyone wants to put that into an answer, they'll get credit. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you fixed your issue with `width`. But I think your problem was elsewhere.

`div#slot` has a property of `flex: auto 1 auto` which is not valid and ignored. `div#slot` is a child of a flex element `div#tab-wrapper` so its width is the minimum width of the content. This is why the tabs are shrinked.

Now if you replace `flex: auto 1 auto` by `flex: 1 1 auto` (`flex-grow: 1`) `div#slot` will have a width of 100% the width of `div#tab-wrapper` and `flex: 1 1 10em` will work as expected on tabs.

```css
#tab-wrapper,
#slot {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#slot {
  /* previouly flex: auto 1 auto; */
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.tab {
  flex: 1 1 10em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

#new {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="tab-wrapper">
  <div id="slot">
    <div class="tab">test1</div>
    <div class="tab">test2</div>
  </div>
  <span id="new">✚</span>
<div>
```

Comment: It appears you're correct about `auto` being an invalid option for `flex-grow` ( or `flex-shrink` for that matter ), but this doesn't exactly answer the question.

If you set `#slot` to `flex: 0 1 auto` and `.tab` to `flex: 1 1 auto`, along with `width: 10em` and provide a `min-width` and a `max-width` ( I chose `2.5em` and `15em` respectively ), then it gives the behavior I was looking for.

Comment: I filled the gap in my understanding about `width`, `min-width` and `max-width` with this article https://css-tricks.com/making-width-and-flexible-items-play-nice-together/. I was previously under the impression that those are ignored by flexbox.